# DNS Tunneling - Iodine Issue

Tags: linux, dns, tunnel, iodine

I am trying to set up DNS tunneling using Iodine on a VPS from Google Cloud Compute Engine. I have a firewall rule to allow UDP:53 however I get an error when trying to connect:

```
Opened IPv4 UDP socket
Sending DNS queries for tunnel.mydomainn.com to 8.8.8.8
Autodetecting DNS query type (use -T to override)Opened IPv4 UDP socket
.....................
No suitable DNS query type found. Are you connected to a network?
If you expect very long roundtrip delays, use -T explicitly.
(Also, connecting to an "ancient" version of iodined won't work.)
```

When I use the [testing service](http://code.kryo.se/iodine/check-it/), it tells me:

```
Looking for nameserver for domain.com.. got jack.ns.cloudflare.com (at 173.x.x.121).
Resolving delegation of tunnel.ngtapps.com at 173.x.x.121... to vps.ngtapps.com (at 35.x.x.x).

Expecting iodined to be accessible at 35.x.x.x... no reply.
```

I'm lost as to what the issue is. Could someone please explain it and tell me what I need to do to fix?

Comment: Also having the same error. Were you able to fix this? By the way, I'm using AndIodine (Android client)

Answer (score 1):

Are you invoking `iodine` or `iodined`? I just ran into this and puzzled for hours before figuring out I was invoking the server with `iodine` not `iodined`.